# Name for date format "dd day of MMMM, yyyy"

Tags: .net, datetime-format

I'm working in a platform that has minimal .NET support, so we often have to roll our own utility methods for dates, string, etc. The whole team has .NET backgrounds, so we try to name these something familiar/suggestive of similar .NET methods.

We deal with a lot of legal verbiage, and end up writing dates in a specific way: "this 5th day of March, 2020". I need to write a function that takes a date and returns it formatted as such.

Is there an *existing* DateTime format in .NET languages for: "dd day of MMMM, yyyy"? I can't use that, but I'd prefer to use that *name*. I can't find one in the documentation, but I may be missing it.

If not, is there a general term for this format, perhaps from other common languages?

I know this is not strictly a code question, but if I ask at English.StackExchange they'll gripe about it being code-related.

Comment: You can have a look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the 1st 2nd is referred to as the ordinal indicator.

There is no built in support for this concept in the .net framework as it only works in a few languages. In turn the format you are asking for is not directly supported.

You can build it yourself or look at humanize project that aims to fill this gap https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#datetime-to-ordinal-words

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no built-in formatting expression for your requirement, but it is not very complex to write an extension to do the formatting once and for all.

The most important thing is to escape properly all the letters that are normally used in date formatting when you require them as simple text

For example:

```
public static string LegalDateFormat(this DateTime d)
{
    
    int day = d.Day;
    string suffix = (day == 1 ? "\\s\\t" : day == 2 ? "n\\d" : day == 3 ? "r\\d": "\\t\\h");
    
    // string format = $"\\t\\hi\\s i\\s \\t\\he d{suffix} \\da\\y o\\f MMMM, yyyy";
    // better, as proposed by Hans Keﬆing in his comment below
    string format = $"'this is the 'd'{suffix} day of 'MMMM, yyyy";
    return d.ToString(format);
}
```

Of course, date time formatting is very dependent to the current globalization settings and this could be acceptable only for the English culture. If you have the requirement to support different cultures then this is not enough and probably there are some library that could serve you a better solution

Comment: `string format = $"'this is the 'd'{suffix} day of 'MMMM, yyyy";` is more readable (note the single quotes escaping text fragments)

Comment: We're not working in .NET; I might not have been clear on that. It's a proprietary scripting layer based on a bastardized version of JScript. I know how to approach the method design; I'm just asking if there's an existing C# (or other popular language) method/format that I can name it like. Thanks for the answer and sorry for the confusion.